# Unable to connect to Kafka on Kubernetes externally

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, bitnami

I have deployed kafka on minikube by following https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-scalable-kafka-zookeeper-cluster-kubernetes.

I'm able to create kafka topics, publish and consume messages from the topics through `kubectl` commands. When I installed kafka through helm chart, `kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local` is the DNS name within the cluster.

`helm install kafka bitnami/kafka --set zookeeper.enabled=false --set replicaCount=3 --set externalZookeeper.servers=zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local -n kafka`

I have tried in multiple ways, but not able to access this kafka cluster outside. I'm trying to publish messages to a kafka topic through sample producer code in IntelliJ, but the bootstrap server `kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local` is not reachable.

Comment: I suggest starting with https://strimzi.io and reading their documentation about allowing external client access

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Thanks for your suggestion, I've setup kafka with strmzi.io and I'm able to publish/consume messages from outside the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the bootstrap server kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local is not reachable.

That's internal CoreDNS record address, only. You'll need to define a headless service with exposed NodePort and optional TCP LoadBalancer that'll direct Ingress traffic into the cluster, along with an appropriate NetworkPolicy. Search the config for "external" - https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka#traffic-exposure-parameters

Kafka is not unique in this way, so I suggest learning more about accessing k8s services outside the cluster. Or switch back to Docker Compose for simply testing a local Kafka environment with containers.

Note that the advertised listeners setting of each broker pods would need to return their individual, external broker addresses back to the client

Comment: I tried by installing helm with NodePort, below is the services I can see:
```NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S) 
service/kafka                ClusterIP   x.x.x.x        <none>        9092/TCP
service/kafka-0-external     NodePort    x.x.x.x        <none>        9094:32074/TCP
service/kafka-1-external     NodePort    x.x.x.x        <none>        9094:32389/TCP
service/kafka-2-external     NodePort    x.x.x.x        <none>        9094:30996/TCP
service/kafka-headless       ClusterIP   None           <none>        9092/TCP,9093/TCP```

Comment: Along with that, when I try to check kafka topics created, with the command
```./kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server x.x.x.x:32074,x.x.x.x:32389,x.x.x.x:30996```, I'm getting timeout issue. Not sure, what mistake I'm doing. These IPs are the Endpoints displayed in the kafka-headless service.

Comment: The headless service says None for its clusterIP, though

Comment: Yeah, I tried "minikube tunnel" also, bitnami chart didn't work though.